# Validating Motor control architecture using Raspberry Pi Hardware PWM

Tags: pwm, motordriver

I need a validation on what I am doing is correct. please look at the part of schematic shown below. I am driving two linear actuator through rpi 4b. Both Enable pin of each motor driver input is connected to hardware pwm on gpio(). I am driving actuators at 8 Khz PWM frequency. All is working fine , I am able to control and drive actuators at minimum 55% speed by changing duty cycle on motor enable pin of motor driver. Is there a risk of controlling the actuators using this configuration? Is there a possibility that noise or vibration can damage the actuator or motor driver? I have seen one actuator getting damaged and one motor driver circuit not working out of 15 batch . I am trying to link if it is happening because of this configuration or PWM frequency or it might be something else?
[image]

Comment: I think this should be migrated to electrical engineering stack exchange.

Comment: how is it 'C' related?

Comment: Because I am writing its interface in C using wiringpi.h

Comment: Thank you I will migrate it , thank you for your suggestion and all your responses